# why my R can't display words in png format ,and become panes

Tags: r

I have installed R in linux via conda.

the command to install R :

```
conda create -n R -c conda-forge
conda install R
```

My R version: R 3.6.1, I want to plot and save in png format, the words can't display, and become a lot of panes，  but it works nicely when I save it in pdf format. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

my plot code:

```
dat<-read.table("test.fst",header=T)
png("test.png")
plot(dat$POS,dat$WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST)
dev.off()
```

my input data:

```
CHROM   POS WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST
chr1    13273   0.00336442
chr1    14464   0.117861
chr1    14599   0.111578
chr1    14604   0.110681
chr1    14930   0.330811
chr1    15211   0.493186
chr1    49298   -0.00215941
chr1    49554   0.0211625
chr1    51479   0.170572
```

if I use pdf to save the plot, everything is fine
[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

Comment: Please share the code for plots with example data. Most likely you system is missing some fonts.

Comment: @zx8754 Hi, I have shared the code and data, Do you have any suggestion? thank you very much :)

Comment: @Sunnia I would suggest using `dput(dat)` to dump your data, and paste the result into your post. One can then cut and paste into their R session to try to reproduce; it just makes it quicker and easier for people to help.

Comment: I'm not sure why the basic `png` graphic device export is having trouble with the font. But maybe try upgrading by using the `cairoDevice` package, for the Cairo device instead?